# Radiation Reaction Force on particle from the principle of least action

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, action

As one know, according to the ideas of theoretical physics, the equations of motion of particles and the laws of motion of fields (field equations) can be obtained from the principle of least action:

\begin{equation}
S = \int \underbrace{-mcds + \frac{e}{c}A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}}_{\substack{\delta S_{m+mf} = 0 \\ \text{given $A_{\mu}$,} \\ \text{deriving eqns $x^{\mu}$}}} \underbrace{ + \frac{1}{16\pi c}F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} d\Omega }_{\substack{\delta S_{mf + f} = 0 \\ \text{given $x^{\mu}$,} \\ \text{deriving eqns $A_{\mu}$} }}
\end{equation}
(latest uderbrace should be overlaped with term $\frac{e}{c}A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$)

Thus, considering the "particle + field" system, and considering the field given, one can obtain the equation of motion for particles varying  of $S$ in $x^{\mu}$'s. Assuming that the particle motion is given, one can obtain field equations varying of $S$ in $A_{\mu}$'s.

Why one can't derive Radiation Reaction Force on particle from the principle of least action varying $S$ in both $x^{\mu}$ and by $A_{\mu}$?